# after minification of angular js project code , this jquery plugin is not working as it done in general use

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datetimepicker

Its not working but its css working. I placed two fields in my form as startdate and enddate , applied validations as required and date comparisions with form validation. but its not working after all controllers minification. any thought?

http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Answer (score 1):

You said you were using AngularJS. The dependency injection AngularJS breaks when you minify if you don't name the function arguments.

Did you use injection like the following?

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($dep1, $dep2) {
  ..
});
```

When minifying you should do

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$dep1', '$dep2', function($dep1, $dep2) {
  ...
}]);
```

for the minified script to work. I don't know if it's related though.

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere there was an issue minifying those kind of scripts.. it still works un-minified ?